# How do I get a new empty object in my array

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, requirejs, hottowel

I had a simple app that used two viewmodels and requirejs to combine them and all was good, now I've been told I need to have multiple versions of my nested view model so I added an array and my first item is fine but I'm not sure how to add my subsequest items.

On another page the user is asked if they want to add another user and if so I need to navigate back to this page with a new empty `person` object in the `people` array.

- If I use the object supplied by requirejs `people.push(person)`, I get back the existing version rather then a new one
- If I just add a new object to the array `people.push({})`, then my knockout bindings don't work as they are looking for non existent values.

How do I get a "new" `person` into `people`?

here are my view models and view,

**Base**

```
define(['viewmodel/person'], function (person) {
    var vm = {
        people: [],
        peopleIndex: 0,
        currentPerson: currentPerson,
    };

    return vm;

    //#region Internal Methods
    function currentPerson() {
        return vm.people[vm.peopleIndex]
    }
})
```

**Common child**

```
define(['services/logger', ], function (logger) {
    var person = {
        title: "",
        firstName: "",
        lastName: "",
    };

    return person;
})
```

**View**

```
<section>
    <h2 class="page-title" data-bind="text: title"></h2>

    <label for="firstName">Title</label><input type="text" name="firstName" data-bind="value: currentPerson().title" />
    <label for="firstName">Fisrt Name</label><input type="text" name="firstName" data-bind="value: currentPerson().fistName" />
    <label for="firstName">Last Name</label><input type="text" name="firstName" data-bind="value: currentPerson().lastName" />
</section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your current `person` object literal into a `Person` constructor function (you probably want your properties as `ko.observable` in order to the your `value` bindings work):

```
define(['services/logger', ], function (logger) {
    var Person = function() {
        this.title = ko.observable("");
        this.firstName = ko.observable("");
        this.lastName = ko.observable("");
    };
    return Person;
})
```

Then in your viewmodel where you need to create a new person you can use the `new` keyword to create a new instance:

```
define(['viewmodel/person'], function (person) {

    //...
    people.push(new person())
}
```

Or you can make the `people.push({})` work if include all the properties:

```
people.push({
     title: ko.observable(""),
     firstName: ko.observable(""),
     lastName: ko.observable(""),
});
```

this will work but it will introduce duplication in your code so I don't recommend using this approach.

Comment: Thanks, that is what I was missing. I didn't have my view model properties as observables as I thought I only needed oneway data binding, but now that I'm revisiting pages with new context it looks like knockout might be doing some caching of the binding results. *starts reading the doco again*

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your current person object literal into a Person constructor function (you probably want your properties as ko.observable in order to the your value bindings work):

```
define(['services/logger', ], function(logger) {
    var Person = function() {
        this.title = ko.observable("");
        this.firstName = ko.observable("");
        this.lastName = ko.observable("");
    };
    return Person;
})
```

Then in your viewmodel where you need to create a new person you can use the new keyword to create a new instance:

```
define(['viewmodel/person'], function(person) {
    //...
    people.push(new person());
}
```

Or you can make the people.push({}) work if include all the properties:

```
people.push({
    title: ko.observable(""),
    firstName: ko.observable(""),
    lastName: ko.observable(""),
});
```

this will work but it will introduce duplication in your code so I don't recommend using this approach